# vim: command not found

Tags: installation, vim, command-line

I'm trying to install openflow in Ubuntu, but I encounter a problem when installing regression suite. I follow the instruction from openflow website with the below lines

To update the `OF_ROOT` environment variable for your setup:

```
cd ~/   
cp <openflow-dir>/regress/scripts/env_vars .  
vim env_vars
```

but when I run `vim env_vars`, I get a **vim: command not found** error. Why?

Answer (score 20):

Try installing `vim`:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

or you can use a different text editor, like `nano`, which may be easier to use:

```
nano env_vars
```

Comment: This is needed because vim is not installed on Ubuntu by default.

Comment: I tried this and it gives the same error but for "apt-get" instead. (*"apt-get: command not found"*)